# Unable to find good bind path format when deploying AWS Lambda via GitHub action and serverless framework

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, serverless-framework, github-actions

Trying to use serverless framework to deploy AWS Lambda with Github action running on Windows Server 2019 but deployment fails with

> Unable to find good bind path format

This is how my action template looks like:

```
name: deploy-aws-lambda
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: eu-west-1
      - name: Serverless Deploy
        run: npm run-script deploy
```

The script *deploy* runs `serverless deploy`

My `serverless.yml`

```
service: test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: eu-west-1
  memorySize: 256
  timeout: 15

functions:
  main:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
      
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - .vscode/**
    - .github/**
```

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is test",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless": "^2.33.1",
    "serverless-python-requirements": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "serverless deploy"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Sample lambda function `handler.py`

```
import json


def main(event, context):
    body = {
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "input": event
    }

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(body)
    }

    return response
}
```

Sample `requirements.txt`

```
requests
numpy
```

Log and trace on after calling deploy:

```
Serverless: Generated requirements from D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\requirements.txt in D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\.serverless\requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\UnitedIncome\serverless-python-requirements\Cache\5e61405b67ffec41db1bbd78f432bc4fd4ccdf0af1764200fd7a3859b7126a39_slspyc\requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python3.8
 
  Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: Unable to find good bind path format
      at getBindPath (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\docker.js:152:9)
      at installRequirements (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:198:39)
      at installRequirementsIfNeeded (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:556:3)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.installAllRequirements (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:635:29)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.tryCatcher (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
      at _drainQueueStep (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
      at _drainQueue (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

Locally this deployment process works just fine on my Windows 10 machine, though I'm using Docker Desktop and the machine in question is Windows Server 2019. Any workarounds or fixes for this problem?

Comment: Ending up with same error on Windows 10 but enabling file sharing on required directories in Docker Desktop fixes this. Wonder how this can be achieved in this case.

Comment: Docker version is the latest from https://dockermsft.azureedge.net/dockercontainer/DockerMsftIndex.json.

Comment: can you share the link to enable docker file sharing in Windows 10

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

add  "return servicePath;" line at the end of getBindPath function in D:\a\telegram-bot\telegram-bot\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\docker.js:152:9

Comment: If that's a fix then I think it should be reported as issue at https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/issues